# django class based view many to many field display selected values

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have a form created with Update View class based view. It displays every value in input type fields from database, except values of many to many field. 

What should i insert into view or maybe model so user will see what options they have slected (like in built-in admin module).

This is my view:

```
class StudentUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):

form_class = StudentForm
model = Student
template_name = 'forms/modify.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(StudentUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['year'] = Setting.objects.get(id=2)
    return context

def form_valid(self, form):
    if self.request.is_ajax():
        self.object = form.save()
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps("success"),
            mimetype="application/json")
    return super(StudentUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)

def form_invalid(self, form):
    if self.request.is_ajax():
        return HttpResponseBadRequest(json.dumps(form.errors),
            mimetype="application/json")
    return super(StudentUpdateView, self).form_invalid(form)
```

**EDIT:**

This is my model used, as Model Form
And StudentForm does not exist

```
class Student (models.Model):
name = models.CharField(u'Imię', max_length=40)
surname = models.CharField(max_length=80)
email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
subjects = models.ManyToManyField(Subjects, blank=True)
programs = models.ManyToManyField(Programs, editable=False)
history = models.CharField(max_length=50, editable=False)
added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s %s'(self.name, self.surname)

class StudentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
```

Comment: Please, show your Student and StudentForm code.

Comment: It should work as you expect. Show the form template or at least the form part of it.